# IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`) . .

Tags: python, pymc3, best-fit-curve

I am using pymc3 to find a best fit for a 3D surface. This is the code that I am using.

```
with Model() as model:
# specify glm and pass in data. The resulting linear model, its likelihood and                                                                                                   
# and all its parameters are automatically added to our model.                                                                                                                   
glm.glm('z ~ x**2 + y**2 + x + y + np.sin(x) + np.cos(y)' , flatimage)
start = find_MAP()
step = NUTS(scaling=start) # Instantiate MCMC sampling algorithm                                                                                                                 
trace = sample(2000, step, progressbar=False) # draw 2000 posterior samples using NUTS sampling
```

I got an error in this line:

```
glm.glm('z ~ x**2 + y**2 + x + y + np.sin(x) + np.cos(y)' , flatimage)
```

The error is :

```
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

I had tried to fix it by changing sin(x) and cos(y) to np.sin(x) and np.cos(y), but that didn't work, and I don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is related to your definition of `flatimage`. You need your data labeled for the glm module to work. Something like this:

```py
# synthetic data (just an example)
x = np.random.normal(size=100)
y = np.random.normal(size=100)
z = x**2 + y**2 + x + y + np.sin(x) + np.cos(y)

data = dict(x=x, y=y, z=z) # a pandas dataframe will also work

with pm.Model() as model:
    pm.glm.glm('z ~ x**2 + y**2 + x + y + np.sin(x) + np.cos(y)' , data)
    start = pm.find_MAP()
    step = pm.NUTS(scaling=start)         
    trace = pm.sample(2000, step, start)
```

Check [this](http://twiecki.github.io/blog/2013/08/12/bayesian-glms-1/) example for other details.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me! @aloctavodia